# Does every function $X^n \to Y$ for $X, Y$ finite extend to a linear transformation between finite vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have any arbitrary function $f : X^n \to Y$, where $X, Y$ are finite sets and $n > 0$. Then is there necessarily a finite vector space $V$ containing $X$ and a finite vector space $W$ containing $Y$ so that $f$ is the restriction of a linear transformation $\phi : V^n \to W$?

The $n=1$ case [is pretty easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340932/is-every-function-between-finite-sets-a-restriction-of-a-morphism-of-finite-abel): just let $V$ be the free $K$-vector space on $X$, where $K$ is any finite field, and let $W$ be any $K$-vector space containing $Y$; since $X$ is now a basis of $V$, then $f : X^n \to Y$ automatically extends linearly to a (unique) linear transformation $V^n \to W$.

Does the same kind of result hold for $n > 1$? If $X$ and $Y$ do not embed in vector spaces so that $f$ extends to a linear transformation, then can we relax the requirements and instead just require that $X$ and $Y$ embed in finite abelian groups so that $f$ extends to a group homomorphism?

It seems that the naive attempt of letting $V$ again be a free vector space over $X$, and then extending $f$ to a map $V^n \to W$, where $W$ just contains $Y$, does not work, since $V^n$ is of dimension $n\left|X\right|$, while $\left|X^n\right| = \left|X\right|^n$ instead; and if we instead say that $V^n$ itself should be a free vector space over $X^n$, then this would require that $\dim V = \frac{1}{n}\left|X\right|^n$, so in particular we have an unnatural requirement that $n | \left|X\right|^n.$

Comment: Take tensor products?

Comment: @Hayden could you explain more? Indeed $f$ naturally extends to a linear transformation $\left(K^\left|X\right|\right)^{\bigotimes n} \to W$, but I want a linear transformation from $V^n$ instead (for some $V$).

Comment: You can simply take $V$ to be a free vector space over $X^n$. Now $f$ can be extended to $\phi:V\to W$. Adding missing $n-1$ coordinates is trivial.

Comment: @freakish : I believe $X^n$ is supposed to be contained in $V^n$ diagonally, not in the first component.

Comment: @freakish I need $f$ to be a particular restriction of the linear transformation: the restriction needs to be the same in each "position" of $V^n$, i.e. $f$ is restricted to $X^n \subseteq V^n$. (As Matthias said.)

Comment: @feralin Ah, I see now that you want something specifically of the form $V^n$. The tensor power is ultimately the same as the free vector space over $X^n$.

Comment: Since the elements of $X^n$ will always be linear dependent in $V^n$ (if $X$ has at most two elements and $n > 1$), you will definitely need the corresponding relations between elements of $Y$ in $W$, so you will not be able to take the free vector space on $Y$ as $W$.

Comment: @freakish You're assuming that $(0,1)+(1,0)=(1,1)$, but we don't know what the vector space structures are. There's no reason to suggest that the vector space structure needs to respect what the sets $X$ and $Y$ might think they are.

Comment: @freakish : That is my point. The meaning you are implying is *not* apparent in the set $Y$. You could take a different $W$ (include $Y$ such that the sum of the first element is twice the other).

Comment: @Hayden Yeah, that was my bad. Anyway it still seems to fail. Take $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{a',b',c',d'\}$ with $n=2$. Then $f(a,a)=a', f(a,b)=b', f(b,a)=c', f(b,b)=d'$. Now assuming extension $c'+b'=F(b,a)+F(a,b)=F(a+b,a+b)=F(a,a)+F(b,b)=a'+d'$ which cannot be true.

Comment: @freakish Why can't that be true?

Comment: @freakish I might just be being dumb, but how can we assume that $f(b,a) + f(a,b) = f(a+b, a+b)$? $f$ extends to a bilinear map, which does not (I think) necessarily have to be symmetric.

Comment: @feralin What do you mean bilinear? You want it to be linear. It's just by the definition of linearity.

Comment: @Hayden Because $a',b', c',d'$ are supposed to be linearly independent in $W$? If not, then this question is trivial.

Comment: @freakish I don't see anywhere it says that they need to be linearly independent.

Comment: @Hayden Yeah, well, as Hagen noted you can simply replace $d'$ with $b'$ (in my solution) to obtain yet another contradiction. But to be honest this question is far from being clear about what exactly is required here.

Comment: @freakish it turns out that I was just being dumb! Yes, $f(b,a)+f(a,b)$ should equal $f(a+b,a+b)$ by linearity of $\phi$. I'm sorry the question was not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $X=\{a,b\}$, $Y=\{c,d\}$, $n=2$, $f(a,a)=f(a,b)=f(b,a)=c$, $f(b,b)=d$.
Then we need
$$c+d=\phi(a,a)+\phi(b,b)=\phi(a,b)+\phi(b,a)=c+c$$
and so $c=d$, contradiction.